# Extracting the data

Tags: csv

I have a IsHoliday, WeeklySales and DepartmnentCategory column and I want to know the total WeeklySales if my IsHoliday flag is true and DepartmentCategory is eadible.How to do it? Please suggest.

Comment: I am using R studio.

Comment: Sonu Singh, edit your post with the tag [tag:rstudio].